# How to make a resolver for a custom scalar apply in a graphql code gen file?

Tags: typescript, graphql

Im currently trying to reach out for some graphql questions, so if anyone works with graphql, let me know if you can help out. Im trying to implement a  resolver for a custom scalar in my graphql typescript setup, and im specifically trying to implement a Time scalar, where the backend is going to send over a string, and i want to convert that into a Dayjs type, and send that over to the client. I have a conversion function that is currently doing this for me in my types file, but i want to remove that and have the graphql code generator that i have , do this for me. Problem is im having a tough time plugging in this resolver in a place where it is implemented, and ideally i would want it somehwere in the codegen so it affects multiple places where this scalar Time is used. So far i cant seem to implement this correctly where this conversion from string to Dayjs is happening without that conversion function.

Put me on to some wisdom/insight if you have some suggestions on how to approach.